Expectation bounds on supremum of family of martingales
Suppose I fix a filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{F}, P)$ and on it a Brownian motion $B$. Let $\tau_\alpha$ denote a set of stopping times which satisfies $\sup_\alpha \tau_\alpha \leq M$ almost surely, and $f_\alpha(t)$ be some bounded adapted processes which depend on some parameter $\alpha \in \mathcal{A}$, where $\mathcal{A}$ is a topological space. Suppose that $\alpha \mapsto \tau_\alpha$ and $(\alpha,t) \mapsto f_\alpha(t)$ are continuous maps. I have looked for a very long time to try and find results which imply that
$$E\left( \sup_\alpha \left|\int_0^{\tau_\alpha} f_\alpha(t) dB_t \right| \right) < \infty,$$ and have had no luck, which causes me to be convinced that it is probably false. On the off chance that anyone can point me in the direction of a good resource on this type of topic, it would be hugely appreciated. Thanks!

When you say $f_\alpha$ are bounded, what precisely do you mean? Do you mean a bound for all $\omega\in \Omega$?

If the optimal $\alpha$ is achieved, you can apply Ito's isometry if you assume $f_\alpha$ are bounded in this sense (or at the least, $L^2$).

I mean $P(|f_\alpha(t)| \leq K, \forall \alpha \in \mathcal{A}) = 1$ for a fixed constant $K$. It is obvious that $$\sup_\alpha E\left(\left| \int_0^{\tau_\alpha} f_\alpha(t) dB_t\right|\right) \leq K \sqrt{M}$$ by Ito isometry. This, unfortunately, tells me nothing about when one brings the supremum inside the expectation. Even if the supremum in the question is attained, it would be attained path by path, so this cannot be used.

By that I mean if there exists $\alpha^(\omega)$ such that $$\int_0^{\tau_{\alpha^(\omega)}} f_{\alpha^(\omega)}(t) dB_t = \sup_\alpha \int_0^{\tau_\alpha} f_\alpha(t) dB_t,$$ one cannot use isometry in this case. I agree this would be the case if one knew that $f_{\alpha^(\omega)} (\omega, t)$ were adapted, but I can't verify this and conecture it isn't the case, since $\alpha^*$ needs to know all the trajectories up to $\sup_\alpha \tau_\alpha$. Also, I'm not looking to assume that the supremum is indeed attained. This would still be a very interesting result, though.

@qp212223 can you provide any more details about the $\tau_{a}$ or $f_{\alpha}$? If possible, please include all the details in your post by editing it.

Not full-answer, just a long comment. Here we study the process
$$X_{a}:=\int_{0}^{\tau_a}f_a(s)dB_{s}.$$
By Itô isometry we have the difference
$$E[|X_a-X_b|^2]=E|\int_{[0,\infty)}(f_{a}(s)1_{\tau_{a}(s)}-f_{b}(s)1_{\tau_{b}(s)})dB_s|^2=\int_{[0,\infty)}E(f_{a}(s)1_{\tau_{a}(s)}-f_{b}(s)1_{\tau_{b}(s)})^2ds$$
and so suppose we can bound this by $cd(a,b)^{1+\beta}$ for some $\beta>0$, where $d$ is some distance on $\mathcal{A}$. Then by Kolmogorov continuity theorem (pg.353 "A.3 Continuity criteria" in "The Malliavin Calculus and Related Topics"), we get
$$E[\sup_{d(\alpha,a_{0}) \leq L}|X_{\alpha}|^{2}]<\infty$$
for any $L>0$.
So the main question is whether you have any Lipschitz-type bounds
$$\int_{[0,\infty)}E(f_{a}(s)1_{\tau_{a}(s)}-f_{b}(s)1_{\tau_{b}(s)})^2ds\leq cd(a,b)^{1+\beta}.$$
(In "Tail behaviour of multiple random integrals and U-statistics", it seems that they also study supremum over function-spaces similarly to what you do. )
